# I'm having trouble understanding what this problem is asking me

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, systems-of-equations, graphing-functions

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLLTR.png)

So my problem is that I dont know how to solve it... I have learned about system of inequalities and that kinda stuff, but I never got anything like this. I do not want anyone to solve the problem for me, however If you could explain to me what the problem is asking me to do in a less complicated form that would help, also after you explain, could you tell me how it relates to lines, points, regions, and no intersection. If its impossible to explain this to me without solving then I'm fine with that, but if its possible not to that'd be great 
*Thank you for the help*

P.S: I understand what lines and regions are but im also a little confused with what they mean by a point, and no intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set theoretic explanation:

An object (line or a graph) is basically a set of points in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Let there be 2 objects $O_1$ and $O_2$.

The question asks..

Does there exist $O_1\ \&\ O_2$ such that

> a. $O_1\cap O_2=\{\text{exactly $1$ point}\}$
>
> b. $O_1\cap O_2=\{y:\text{If } y_1,y_2,y_3\in O_1\cap O_2, y_1,y_2,y_3 \text{ form a straight line }\}$
>
> c. $O_1\cap O_2=\{x:\text{the area of the region containing the $x$'s is $\gt 0$}\}$
>
> d. $O_1\cap O_2=\{\phi\}$

Comment: Ok Id like to make this clear that im only 3/5 through algrbra 1 so I havent really learned complicated sayings and ive only seen a few. What does "∩" mean and what do you mean by "Obejects". So i know im being a little greedy and I dont blame you if you'd rather not answer but could you explain each a, b, c, d in a less algrbac form and more saying what it means cause im very confused with the two equations for B, and C

Comment: @kazar4 Okay. So there is a simple solution (as you don't want rigour in the answer).Do you know 1> How to draw a straight line, and 2>What is the region covered by $ax+b\le c$ , $a,b,c$ real numbers?

Comment: Ive never seen straight lines, or regions put into the form that was shown in the answer. Ive always had lines in slope-intercpet form, point intercept form, or standerd form. For regions Ive worked with plotting regions on the graph from inequalitirs and then finding the points that satisfy the solution. To be honest this question came from my online course im taking, and ive already noticed many times that my course is really bad. Just wondering is this even a part of algebra 1?

Comment: @kazar4 Don't get shocked, just because the question has a new approach. I get, you know how to draw a straight line, as well as a region right? Then ,(with full freedom) try to draw 2 straight lines which have (for example , 1c) more than 1 point in common, but the points in common don't lie on a straight line.

Comment: Wouldn't one of the lines have to be curved in order for 2 different lines to have 2 points in common but not be a straight line or infintely many solutions?

Comment: @kazar4 Exactly, and Look , you have got the answer for 1c. 2 **straight lines** with the condition in 1c **cannot** be drawn.

Comment: Ok I get the line problem now, I already gave you the checkmark too, but I have two more questions what does 1c. mean (the part about region), and aslo what is the difference between part 1 and 2

Comment: @kazar4 In part 1, you have only straight lines, in part 2, you have regions on either side of straight lines. For example $y-x\le 1\implies$ the entire region below the line(inclusive) $y=x+1$.